# Gnu make Windows *virtual memory exhausted*

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I am using a windows version of gnu make 4.3 (https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/)
it is build with a provided bat file as x64 appliaction.
On one project which does have about 1100 files (~550 cpp files and the same number of headers) I get always

`virtual memory exhausted`

Did someone know a solution?

EDIT:

Looks like x64 Version of gnu make crashes. 32 Bit Version works.

Comment: My guess would be you're using a 32-bit version of make

Comment: no, the batch file for building windows explictly states x64 configuration

Comment: are you sure it is actually built for 64-bit though?

Comment: Please paste the _exact_ output you see.  Is it really just that string alone, or is there more to the output than that?

Comment: My suspicion is you have some kind of infinite recursion in your makefile.  Try running with `make -d` and see what's going on when you get that message.  You probably want to redirect it to a file.

Comment: its print two lines of subsequent make calls and then virtual memory exhausted. The complete project i am compiling contains 50 sub projects all works except for one. the only thing that is different it does have the most files

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling with less active CPU cores such as `make -j 2` or `make -j 1`.

Comment: it happens single threaded. btw windows version of gnu make only supports ```-j ``` without number of prozessors.

Comment: Could you try compiling and looking at the RAM usage of Make in task manager?

Comment: i have 32GB. make just use 800MB in peak

Comment: It's not true that the Windows version of GNU make only supports `-j` without a number.  It has supported `-j` with a restricted number of jobs since GNU make 4.0 (released in 2013).

Comment: ahh, ok, well it does run into the same issue with -j1 or without -j option